# Django scheduled (template) modules

Tags: django, templates, scheduling

What I am trying to do is to architect "dynamic" modules on my website.

Assume I have a blog, with two columns.

Left column contains a post, right column contains "`modules`" ("**Most popular posts**", "**Tags**" etc).

Some of the modules will be *unrelated* to the post (ex. "**Tags**"), and some will be *independent* (ex.**Blog Roll**).

On the *template* level - **what is the best way to "include" these modules?** (each will have a different markup/different model).

On the *back-end* level - **how can I add a schedule to the "unrelated" modules so they are displayed during particular days/hours?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use include and block tags
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance

to display something based on some variable. you can do something like this
in views

```
def foo(request):
    if day=="monday":
       show_tags=True
    else:
       show_tags=False
    return render_to_response('template.html', {'show_tags': show_tags})
```

and in template.html

```
{% if show_tags %}
   {% include 'tags_template.html' %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I should have added that I would like these modules to be scheduled in admin. Hard coding the date is not ideal. + for the include block.

Comment: this is just an example. To shedule this in admin interface you should create model with required conditions, register it and check them in views like in my example